# Custom Hibernate Component Tuplizers for composite-id elements in XML mappings

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I created custom hibernate [ComponentTuplizer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-tuplizers.html) for POJOs and successfully used it with `<component/>`:

```
    <component name="location" class="com.Location">
                <tuplizer entity-mode="pojo" class="com.ObjenesisComponentTuplizer"/>
                <!-- ......... -->
    </component>
```

But when I came to `<composite-id/>`, it appeared that there is a [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8259) in hibernate schema definition (I've checked `hibernate-mapping-4.0.xsd` and `hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd`) that doesn't allow to define tuplizers for composite-ids (even though it works fine via `@Tuplizer` annotation in class).

Is there any way to workaround this bug? (xml mapping is mandatory in my case, so I cant switch to annotation-based mapping).

Comment: Did you find a solution or a work-around?